# PHP - How to detect user location

Tags: php, location, subdomain, geoip

I am developing web application and i need to know the location of the user they connecting from

For example this website [www.craigslist.org](http://craigslist.org)  it can detect my location and redirect me to sub domain 
So, it's redirect to:

[cairo.craigslist.org](http://cairo.craigslist.org)

[boston.craigslist.org/](http://boston.craigslist.org/)

What is the best way to do that with PHP ?

**PART TWO**

How can i make it redirect to subdomain with country/city ? like the above example ?

Answer (score 1):

In pure PHP without a 3rd party service, take a look at the GeoIP extension library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

You'll be highly limited using this however to country, region, and ISP.  I think the State and City longitude and latitude starts getting less accurate.

You could also check out https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php   which seems to be a library intended to replace GeoIP.

Comment: link only answers are discuraged

Comment: @Ray thanks for your answers ... how can i make it redirect to subdomain ?

Comment: @Marc J After obtaining the location (lets call it `$location`), you could use a simple location-header for redirecting:
`header('Location: http://'.$location.'.example.com/');`

Comment: @A.Fink ... shall i create subdomains with all countries/cities ?!!

Comment: @MarcJ You could do, but i think this is not useful. If you make location less accourate, like continent or maybe country (would still be much), it could be useful.